# A captured variable is not const but it does not move

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider the code below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string v = "abc";

    auto func = [v] () // mutable makes v move
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_const_v<decltype(v)>);
    
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v), std::string>);
    
        //it does not move
        auto a = std::move(v);

        std::cout << "v: " << v;
    };

    func();

    return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
v: abc
```

Why `v` does not move?

As far, as I can guess, without `mutable` keyword something should be const-qualified. Where is this `const`?

Comment: Your test is unreliable because after move construction the moved-from instance is in an unspecified state. It isn't necessarily empty. For example if SSO is being used move construction might just be equivalent to copy construction.

Comment: *Where is this const?*  The const is implicit.  The `mutable` negates the implicit const.