# What mechanism prevents captured variables from being moved?

Tags: c++, c++20

I did some further experimentation on the topic of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210351/a-captured-variable-is-not-const-but-it-does-not-move) and have another one.

Consider the code below where, as I expeded, both `l_ref` are `r_ref` are `const`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Func
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_const_v<decltype(v)>);

        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v), std::string>);

        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(this), const Func*>);

        auto& l_ref = v;

        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(l_ref), const std::string&>);

        //my idea was that it does not move because it is const r-value reference
        auto&& r_ref = std::move(v);

        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(r_ref), const std::string&&>);

        std::cout << "v: " << v;
    }

    std::string v;
};
```

Now consider the following lambda were wired things start to happen and `l_ref` and `r_ref` are not const:

```
int main()
{
    std::string v = "abc";

    auto func = [v]()
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_const_v<decltype(v)>);

        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v), std::string>);

        auto& l_ref = v;

        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(l_ref), std::string&>);

        auto&& r_ref = std::move(v);

        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(r_ref), std::string&&>);

        //what happens here?
        auto a = std::move(v);

        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a), std::string>);

        std::cout << "v: " << v;
    };

    func();

    return 0;
}
```

`v` should not move at line `auto a = std::move(v);` because lambda is not `mutable` so it is something similar to `void operator() const` of the `struct Func`, but at the same time `v` is not  `const` and `std::move(v)` is non-const r-value reference, so what mechanism prevents move constructor of `std::string` from being called?

Comment: Capturing `v` by value `[v]` makes a _copy_ of `v`, also named `v`.  That `v` is const in the body of your lambda, since the lambda is not mutable.

Comment: @MarekR yes that is true, the question is why `auto a = std::move(v);` does not call move constructor while formally `std::move(v)` is non-const r-value reference. Where is the rule that prevents this?

Comment: @DrewDormann why `static_assert(!std::is_const_v<decltype(v)>);` does not fail then?

Comment: Also, `move(v)` does not affect the constness of `v`.  It produces a `std::string const &&`.

Comment: @DrewDormann yes, `std::move` is `static_cast<remove_reference_t<_Ty>&&>(_Arg)` so it does not affect constness.

Comment: Are you compiling on MSVC? Cause `l_ref` and `r_ref` absolutely should be references to const, and they are on gcc and clang.

Comment: @Barry yes, they are non-const with MSVC 2022 and const with GCC.

Comment: Yeah that's just an MSVC bug.

Comment: All compilers behave in same way: https://godbolt.org/z/Wbv8ePY4o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move and copy constructors are both part of the same overload set. The compiler will either choose the copy or the move constructor according to the value category and const-ness of the arguments.

You second example is wrong and won't compile according to the standard. `decltype(l_ref)` and `decltype(r_ref)` are indeed const. See [this live example](https://godbolt.org/z/7abrKcjdW).

MSVC seem to accept the code, but this is a compiler bug. You should [report such problem to the microsoft msvc developpers](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=62&entry=problem).

To prove visual studio is wong and that the variable is indeed const, look at the assembly generated (unmangled):

```
call    std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const &)
```

As you can see, it calls the copy constructor, not the move constructor according to the function parameter:

```
std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const &
```

Comment: reported, see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Wrong-const-ness-of-captured-variables-i/10109769